# Inverse image of a maximal ideal under a morphism of finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let 
$$
f: A\to B
$$
be a morphism of finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, suppose $\mathfrak{m}\unlhd B$ is a maximal ideal, I want to show that $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$ is a maximal ideal of $A$. Consider the morphism 
$$
A\to B/\mathfrak{m}, 
$$
$$
a\mapsto f(a)+\mathfrak{m},
$$
this has kernel $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$, by the first isomorphism theorem we get
$$
A/ f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m}) \cong \frac{f(A)\cap \mathfrak{m}}{\mathfrak{m}},
$$
so, RHS is a field, so LHS is a field and $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$ is maximal. I think that my proof is wrong, probably I got RHS wrong and I am not using the fact that these are finitely generated or over $\mathbb{C}$ at all. What is the correct proof?

Comment: The image of $\pi\circ f\colon A\to B/\mathfrak{m}$ ($\pi\colon B\to B/\mathfrak{m}$ the canonical projection) is a finitely generated algebra and a subring of a field. Is it a field?